# minicart customization from default html

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

i wrote this code in default.html
`app\design\frontend\Smartwave\grocery\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\item\default.html`

```
<div data-bind="text: wahaj">gg  </div>
```

but i am confuse where i write this js

```
function AppViewModel() {
            this.wahaj = ko.observable("ko run ");
                 }

  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
</script>
```

Comment: you can add it to your minicart.js under web/js/view

Comment: @SukumarGorai i added this but my js not working help me plz  
function AppViewModel() {
            this.wahaj = ko.observable("ko run ");
                 }
            
  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

Comment: Can you add your js code as well where you added?

Comment: @SukumarGorai i added it in default.html  <div data-bind="text: wahaj">gg  </div>

Comment: did you try it by adding to minicart.js?